# How to handle may panic if I know it is imposible to panic in rust

Tags: if-statement, parsing, rust, error-handling, match

I have a error on the first parsing: may panic if the index is out of bounds.
But the if before parsing shoud handle this.
How to handle the error correctly?

```
print!("Write 2 ints separated by space: ");
let mut nums_string: String = String::new();
stdout().flush().expect(ERR_MSG_STDOUT_FLUSH);
stdin()
    .read_line(&mut nums_string)
    .expect(ERR_MSG_STDIN_READ_LINE);
let nums_str_vec: Vec<&str> = nums_string.trim().split(' ').collect();
let num1: i32;
let num2: i32;
if nums_str_vec.len() == 2 {
    num1 = match nums_str_vec[0].parse() {
        Err(_) => panic!("Wrong input"),
        Ok(_) => nums_str_vec[0].parse().unwrap(),
    };
    num2 = match nums_str_vec[1].parse() {
        Err(_) => panic!("Wrong input"),
        Ok(_) => nums_str_vec[1].parse().unwrap(),
    };
} else {
    panic!("Wrong input");
}
```

Is possible to handle error without if and use only the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for handling "may panic" if you know it won't panic is to not repeat the code that may panic.

If you have already determined that it is a number by matching the `Ok` case, you do not need to parse it again.

The number is contained in the `Ok` value, which you currently ignore. Use it!

```
Ok(n) => n,
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible to handle error without if and use only the match?

Complemeting mkrieger1's answer, a few additional transformations before the vec will give you a much simpler match thanks to [slice patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#slice-patterns):

```rust
let nums: Vec<Result<i32, _>> = nums_string.trim().split_whitespace().map(str::parse).collect();
match nums[..] {
    [Ok(n1), Ok(n2)] => println!("{} {}", n1, n2),
    _ => println!("Wrong input"),
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is my first time with rust. I can not fully understand your code. After some more time with rust I definitely look at this solution.